# How to make complex conditions look nice and save the number of statements?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

In my java application I have a huge set of conditions which decides just one action. My question is how to make it look nice (I use NetBeans so I'd prefer solution that will not be broken by its code formatting function). I'd also like to have there as low amount of if/else statements as possible, because I *think* it will make it faster.

My original code was a mess, so I made an action diagram:[image: complex action diagram full of conditions]. [Take a copy](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fevh-3vWebwYKiugC3Wb9eIwXcnWDQzlSaPJLeNT-VU/edit) if you want to play with it. Please keep in mind that the diagram is not perfect as to UML *syntax*, partly because I made it using google docs.

This is the code:

```
if (!config.get("checkForSpecials") || event.isNotSpecial()) {
    if (config.get("filterMode").equals("blacklist")) {
        if (!itemFilter.contains(event.getItem().getName())) {
            item.process();
        }
    } else if (config.get("filterMode").equals("whitelist")) {
        if (itemFilter.contains(event.getItem().getName())) {
            item.process();
        }
    } else {
        item.process();
    }
}
```

There are two things I don't like about it - the conditions are not too clear (especially when I unfold full method names and config strings), and the fact that the process method call is there three times.

Comment: Perhaps you can start by declaring boolean flags which represent the conditions and have meaningful names.

Comment: http://www.ewernli.com/noif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factoring booleans out and caching return values from method calls can help clarify code.

In addition, plotting all the outcomes on a logic table can help. I use [this tool](http://www.ee.calpoly.edu/media/uploads/resources/KarnaughExplorer_1.html) to help.

With the linked tool:

```
A: config.get("filterMode").equals("blacklist")
B: config.get("filterMode").equals("whitelist")
C: filterContainsName (see below)
```

The tool churns out:

```
(!A && !B) || (!A && C) || (A && !C)
```

Which leads to the code below (with a small tweak that replaces `(!A && C)` with `(B && C)`):

```
boolean filterContainsName = itemFilter.contains(event.getItem().getName());
boolean useBlacklist       = config.get("filterMode").equals("blacklist");
boolean useWhitelist       = config.get("filterMode").equals("whitelist");

if (!config.get("safeMode") || event.isSafe()) {
    if((!useBlackList && !useWhiteList) ||
       ( useWhiteList &&  filterContainsName) ||
       ( useBlackList && !filterContainsName)) {
        item.process();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the code structures that you're used to seeing. I'd argue that nested ifs represent implicit ANDs and this method makes them explicit... I tend to prefer explicit representations of conditions unless there's a tangible benefit to doing it another way (for instance, if evaluating booleans are costly and can be avoided depending on earlier evaluations)

Comment: Upvoted for the explicatory variable names, they are great for ease of reading.

Answer (score 4):

Use maps. The key of the map is the condition/case, the value is a single method class/anonymouse interface that contains the logic for that condition. Whenever you encounter a certain condition/case, you simply do a lookup in the map and execute the related function. This way you can even split up your logic-by-condition into seperate classes (if needed for sake of code beauty). As an added bonus you'll probably gain a performance bonus when the # of conditions > 10.

Comment: Do you have an example of this, or a link to a clarifying blog post?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5JL51udN Some example code. In this example an eventCode is used to find the correct eventhandler. You could create any type of 'case identifier' (the key in the handlers map), given that you can reconstruct it when the event arrives.

Comment: This is rather interesting. However I think that it is too complicated for my application and I also can't fully understand it (I'm new to Java and OOP). If you have a more in-depth article about this, I'm willing to read :)

Comment: Coming back after some time, I now see how this was meant. I actually know how I'd do something like this in JavaScript or Lua (and I've been using this neat method without knowing what I was doing). I don't however know how to use this principle in Java. And I still don't fully understand the pastebin example. Thanks for any further clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Looks good as it is to me. Perhaps you can isolate the valid conditions for calling `item.process()` to a method to make it more easier to understand.

```
if (!config.get("safeMode") || event.isSafe()) {
    if (isItemValidForProcess(config, itemFilter, event)) {
        item.process();
    }
}

boolean isItemValidForProcess(config, itemFilter, event) {
    String filterMode = config.get("filterMode");
    if (filterMode.equals("whitelist")) {
        return itemFilter.contains(event.getItem().getName());
    }
    if (filterMode.equals("blacklist")) {
        return !itemFilter.contains(event.getItem().getName());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the diagram is not that complex:)
There is no loop, and it is rather linear.

Here's a pseudo code that implements it

```
void action()

    if <sort out specials>
        if <is it special>
            return;

    if <check for unsafe items>
        if not <safe items list contains item>
            return;

    if <filter status = on>
        if < filter mode = whitelist>
            if not <item is on filter>
                return;
        else // black list
            if not <item is on filter>
                return;

    // finally!            
    [process item]
```

For really complex diagram, the answer is ... **goto** ...