# if-condition in uml state machine diagram

Tags: uml, state-machine

Considering this situation:

> ...when an order is placed there is a check for availability, if is passed the preparation will start else the order is refused.
>
> If the customer decides to pay with a credit card before starting the preparation the price of the order is locked on the credit card.
>
> When the preparation is completed the order is delivered and if more than 30 minutes from the placement of the order have passed there is a discount of 50%.

My doubt is how to model the if condition in a state machine diagram, I would model it in the following way but I'm not sure it's the right way:

[image]

How should I model if conditions in a state machine diagram?

Comment: See examples http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/online-shopping-user-account-state-diagram-example.html?context=stm-examples and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dicom-hosted-application-uml-state-machine-diagram-example.html?context=stm-examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a UML state machine diagram, conditionals are associated with transitions.  The transition has a 3-part label in the form of "`trigger-signature [guard]/activity`".  `Guard` is the conditional and must evaluate to true in order for the transition to be taken.  All 3 parts of the transition label are optional.

From your problem description, I might define 3 states named "Waiting for Order", "Preparing Order", and "Delivering Order".  There is a transition from "Waiting for Order" to "Preparing Order" and that transition could be labeled "`order placed [order is available] /`".  I opted to leave off the activity because, from the problem description, I don't see any activity associated with this transition.  You could maybe draw another transition labeled "`order placed [order is unavailable] / refuse order`".  However, this transition would start from "Waiting for Order" and return to "Waiting for Order" because we don't change states when the order is refused.  In this transition I included the `refuse order` activity because I assume there is some actual activity associated with refusing an order.

Alternately, I have seen transitions drawn which include a decision diamond where the arrow leading into the diamond is labeled with the `trigger`, one arrow out of the diamond is labeled with `[guard] / activity` and the other arrow out of the diamond is labeled with `[else] / activity`.  I'm not sure whether this is technically correct UML though.

I think that the conditionals that you put in the entry activities for your Preparation and Delivery states are pretty good the way they are.  Because those conditionals seem like they are associated with the activity that occurs upon entry into those states rather than any state transition.

Answer (score 6):

In an UML state diagram, an if-condition should be modeled as a **choice** element, represented by a diamond-shaped symbol. The outgoing transitions must be marked with the corresponding conditions ("guards" in UML terminology) in square brackets. A trigger (event) and a behaviour (action) may be additionally given as described by kkrambo.

Example:
[image: choice example]

[This](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html) and [this](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/diagrams/tutorials/state-machine-diagram-tutorial/) gives some good advice on choices (and state diagrams in general).

Answer (score 0):

This diagram (taken from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267155/how-to-make-complex-conditions-look-nice-and-save-the-number-of-statements)) might help:

[image]

So to answer your question, you didn't do it wrong, it's just a matter of style and readability. As far as I know, UML doesn't really define a standard way to represent conditionals. So just go with what looks best and makes sense.

Comment: The diagram in your example seems like a bad example because it is not a state machine diagram (where are the states?).  It seems more like an activity diagram but I'm not even sure this is valid UML.

Comment: A state machine diagram is going to look pretty much the same anyways, basically what I was trying to say was that there is no universal standard for how to represent conditionals in UML or state machine diagrams (everyone does it differently, including all of the university textbooks), so I was just showing him a nice clean looking way of doing it. He was doing it the right way, so I interpreted his question as what style should be used.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define conditions inside of state element of state machine. Review you diagram. I think , you should some information put on diagram. For example, use choice element to define alternative transition paths. Or draw detailed diagram for "prepare order" and "payment" behaviors from Preparation and Delivery states.

It is not always possible to put all information on the exactly one diagram.